# Rotating a canvas object with keyboard

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

it's my first question.
I'm doing an Asteroids game copy and I've started with spaceship movement, but
I've got a problem with rotating it in canvas in js. The problem is how to stop rotation after pressing key? It's rotating in two directions, but when I release the key, object returns to its initial state.

here is code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup',doKeyUp,true);
    //var x = canvas.width/2;
    //var y = canvas.height/2;
    var keys = new Array();
    function doKeyDown(evt){
        keys[evt.keyCode] = true;
    }
    function doKeyUp(evt){
        keys[evt.keyCode] = false;
    }

    var context = document.getElementById('pageCanvas').getContext('2d');
    var angle = 0;
    var angle2 = 0;
    function convertToRadians(degree) {
        return degree*(Math.PI/180);
    }

    function incrementAngle() {
        angle -= 10;
        if(angle > 360) {
            angle = 0;
        }
    }

    function decrementAngle(){
        angle2 += 10;
        if(angle2>360){
            angle2 = 0;
        }
    }



    function drawRandomlyColoredRectangle() {  

        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0,0,500,500);

        fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
        incrementAngle();
        decrementAngle();


        context.translate(200,200);
        if(37 in keys && keys[37]){
            context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
            console.log("lewo");
        };
        if (39 in keys && keys[39]){ //right
            //x += dx/5;
            //rotacja w prawo
            context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle2));
            console.log("prawo");
        };




        context.fillStyle = "green";
        context.fillRect(-25,-25,50,50);

        context.restore();
    }



   setInterval(drawRandomlyColoredRectangle, 20);
```

and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tomasthall/covyjaLb/2/

Help, please :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the current value of angle in the variable and use it in each rendering frame.

```
if(37 in keys && keys[37]){
    decrementAngle();
};

if (39 in keys && keys[39]){
    incrementAngle();
};

(...)

context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
```

Check and study other fixes and read some tutorials/articles before asking next questions...
http://jsfiddle.net/covyjaLb/3/

Comment: Thanks :D I know, I read a lot of articles etc, but I couldn't find any solution :/